# Cant return a modified Object in a map callback. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, array.prototype.map

This is a route running on node.js/express/mongoose...
'Department' is a Mongoose.js model

1. The first 'Department.find()' call returns an array of objects where each object looks like this:

   `{
     _id: 58a4b5991a1214ff1f2c5406,
     name: 'Information Technology',
     manager: 58a60a581a1214ff1f2c5415,
     parent: 58a4b23c1a1214ff1f2c5405,
     primaryLoc: [ 58a5db4c1a1214ff1f2c5414 ]
   }`
2. I want to return JSON that has the name of the parent deptartment not just the id.
3. I .map() over the returned 'departements' array. Do a Department.FindOne() on the 'Parent' Id. This successfully finds the name of the parent. I then try to add the 'parentName' key to the object.
4. This appears to work as I can `console.log('ParentName' + thisObj.parentName)`
5. No matter what I try though the return object does not contain the added key.

Here's my code:   Thanks in advance!

```
router.get('/departments', function(req, res) {

  Department.find({}, function(err, departments) {
    if (err) throw err

    //Find the names of the parent departments
    let newDepts = departments.map(function(dept) {

      let thisObj = dept
      Department.findOne({ _id : dept.parent })

      .then(function(foundDept){
          if (foundDept) {
            thisObj['parentName'] = foundDept.name
            console.log(`thisObj has the key now?: parentName = ${thisObj.parentName}`) //This works
            console.log(`thisObj: ${thisObj}` ) //Nope. No parentName key?? 
            return thisObj
          } else {
            thisObj['parentName'] = "TopLevelDeptartment"
            return thisObj
          }

      })

    })

    res.json(newDepts)

  })

})
```

With your help here is my new code... Unfortunately `res.body` has 11 null entries. (Right now there is only 11 depts in the dbase)... If I log thisObj to the console after the find() it is a fully populated object so I know the find function is working. I can also log the parentName to the console so I know the findOne() is working. Still missing something?

```
router.get('/departments', function(req, res) {

  Department.find({}, function(err, departments) {
    if (err) throw err


    //Find the names of the parent departments
    Promise.map(departments, function(dept) {
      let thisObj = dept
      Department.findOne({ _id : dept.parent }, function(foundDept){
          if (foundDept) {
            thisObj['parentName'] = foundDept.name
          } else {
            thisObj['parentName'] = "No Parent"
          }
      })

    }).then(function(depts){
      console.log(`depts.length: ${depts.length}`)
      res.json(depts)
    })


  })

})
```

Comment: You are `return`ing from the `then` callback, not from the `map` callback. You'll need to return the promise from the map callback, and use `Promise.all` before awaiting all results and calling `res.json` only when everything is done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have asynchronous actions in your code. You map your departments, but your db calls are runned after object mapping. So you return your original department and after some time your Moongose findOne function return result and you update object which has been already processed. You can see that it is updated, but it won't change original object.

Solution with Bluebird Promises example:

```
var Promise = require('Bluebird')

Promise.map(departments, function(dept) {
      return Department.findOne({ _id : dept.parent }, function(foundDept){
          if (foundDept) {
            dept['parentName'] = foundDept.name
          } else {
            dept['parentName'] = "No Parent"
          }
          return dept
      })
    }).then(function(depts){
      res.json(depts)
    })
```

Bluebird will take care of waiting for your findOne result and at the end will return transformed deperatments.

Comment: The `departments`' `map` method definitely will not be promise aware, it would return an array not a promise. Please remove your first snippet, only the second one works

Comment: I'm new to Bluebird so forgive me if this is a stupid question. In the above example you have `res.json(newDepts)`.... Where is newDepts declared?

Comment: It comes from Promise. After processing all departments, Bluebird is executing your function from .then(...) with deperatments as an argument.

Comment: Thanks for all your help:   Is  `.then(function(depts) { res.json(newDepts) })` a typo?   Should it read: `.then(function(depts) { res.json(depts) })`  ?

Comment: Yes, it's a typo ;)

Comment: I have updated the original question with my new code... Still something is not working. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I've updated my code. You need to return object in promise function and in map you need to return promise.